# Thymeleaf post form doesn't submit data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf, I try to execute a simple form submittion using Thymeleaf and Spring. Controller looks like this

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class BookController {

  private static final String BOOK_BOOKFORM_URL = "book/bookform";

  private BookService bookService;

  @Autowired
  public BookController(BookService bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/book/{id}/show")
  public String showBookById(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("book", bookService.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));

    return "book/bookshow";
  }

  @GetMapping("book/new")
  public String newBook(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("book", new BookCommand());

    return "book/bookform";
  }

  @GetMapping("book/{id}/update")
  public String updateBook(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("book", 
        bookService.findCommandById(Long.valueOf(id)));
     return BOOK_BOOKFORM_URL;
  }

  @PostMapping("book/")
  public String saveOrUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute("book") BookCommand 
    command,
     BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

      bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach(objectError -> {
        log.debug(objectError.toString());
      });

      return BOOK_BOOKFORM_URL;
    }

    BookCommand savedCommand = bookService.saveBookCommand(command);

    return "redirect:/book/" + savedCommand.getId() + "/show";
  }

  @GetMapping("book/{id}/delete")
  public String deleteById(@PathVariable String id) {

    log.debug("Deleting id: " + id);

    bookService.deleteById(Long.valueOf(id));
    return "redirect:/";
  }
}
```

And Thymeleaf form looks like this

```
<body>
<!--/*@thymesVar id="book" type="com.sombra.test.firsttry.model.Book"*/-->
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <form class="form" th:modelAttribute="book" th:object="${book}" 
        th:action="@{/book/}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <div class="pannel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h1 class="panel-title">Змінити інформацію про книгу</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Ім'я:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                 <label>Опубліковано:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="* 
                  {published}"/>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Жанр:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{genre}"/>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label>Рейтинг:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{rating}"/>
               </div>
          </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Book and BookCommand are POJOs converted to each other with Spring's Converter.
When i press submit button, controller method saveOrUpdate neither redirects me to the page with information about the book as it has to do in case of successful saving, nor logs error messages from BindingResult. So, what the reason it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Change this `@PostMapping("book/")` to `@PostMapping("/book/")`

If the above doesnt work then play with the below by removing slash.

`th:action="@{/book/}"` as the problem is with URL matching only.

Answer (score 0):

Use @SessionAttributes  annotation
 like this

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("book")
public class BookController {

  private static final String BOOK_BOOKFORM_URL = "book/bookform";

  private BookService bookService;

  @Autowired
  public BookController(BookService bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/book/{id}/show")
  public String showBookById(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("book", bookService.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));

    return "book/bookshow";
  }

  @GetMapping("book/new")
  public String newBook(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("book", new BookCommand());

    return "book/bookform";
  }

  @GetMapping("book/{id}/update")
  public String updateBook(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("book", 
        bookService.findCommandById(Long.valueOf(id)));
     return BOOK_BOOKFORM_URL;
  }

  @PostMapping("book/")
  public String saveOrUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute("book") BookCommand 
    command,
     BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

      bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach(objectError -> {
        log.debug(objectError.toString());
      });

      return BOOK_BOOKFORM_URL;
    }

    BookCommand savedCommand = bookService.saveBookCommand(command);

    return "redirect:/book/" + savedCommand.getId() + "/show";
  }

  @GetMapping("book/{id}/delete")
  public String deleteById(@PathVariable String id) {

    log.debug("Deleting id: " + id);

    bookService.deleteById(Long.valueOf(id));
    return "redirect:/";
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding @SessionAttributes makes no changes for this case.Any other assumptions?

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Actually, no output. It neither redirects to the page with added record view, nor logs error messages. It just stays on the same page with "/book/" adress.

Comment: i think the form submission is not happening.

Comment: print some message in saveOrUpdate method to check the function is executing or not

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your assumptions and help!
Finally, I found the reason of problem. The issue was about storing the Date from field Published of the form. Spring could't convert inserted string into Date, but for some reason no errors were logged in the block with BindingResult error logging. The solution is adding binder for the Date to controller like this one:

```
 @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new 
    SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true));
 }
```